# Avoid Height Overflow by resizing objects

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova

I am expriementing phonegap in order to develop some multi platform apps for phones with HTML5 and Java Script.

I want an object I'm having in my web page (its a table or div) to shirink to exact size of displays as each phone may have different display, hence I used java script and html like below to get the size of screen (the available size of course) and set it as the height and width of my div, or whatever object I want.

it works till width but when it goes to height I still have a scroll bar. I have no idea where this comes from but I tried many ways to limit the height by even giving a exact size to a parent div.

```
<style>
.dummy {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#900;
}
</style>
<script>
var width = window.screen.availWidth + "px";
var height = window.screen.availHeight + "px";
function load() {
document.getElementById("dummy").style.height = height;
document.getElementById("dummy").style.width = width;
}
</script>
<style>
body {

    margin:0px;

    }
.cont {
    height:100px;}  

</style>
</head>



<body onload="load()">
<div class="cont">
<div class="dummy" id="dummy" onclick="load();"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

what's wrong with this code? why my red div is bigger than the screen height?

thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to making it responsive? Why not just use something like Bootstrap or Ratchet? No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is not wrong in your code. You should known exactly about window.screen.availWidth: is full height device + status bar(not correct with several document, but it is truth). You screen available exactly is use:

```
var width = window.innerWidth + "px";
var height = window.innerHeight + "px";
```